# Average blurring mask produces different results

Tags: image-processing, processing

multiplying each pixel by the average blurring mask  *(1/9)  but the result is totally different.

```java
PImage toAverageBlur(PImage a)
{
   PImage aBlur = new PImage(a.width, a.height);

   aBlur.loadPixels();

   for(int i = 0; i < a.width; i++)
   {
      for(int j = 0; j < a.height; j++)
      {
        int pixelPosition = i*a.width + j;
        int aPixel = ((a.pixels[pixelPosition] /9));

        aBlur.pixels[pixelPosition] = color(aPixel);
      }
   }
   aBlur.updatePixels();

   return aBlur;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this piece of code?

Comment: @Jordaan Mylonas: to average blur a normal image

Comment: "Average Blur", to my knowledge, isn't a standard, well defined term. Could you elaborate or demonstrate what you mean by it, as there could be many interpretations of that term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are not applying an average filter, you are only scaling the image by a factor of 1/9, which would make it darker. Your terminology is good, you are trying to apply a 3x3 moving average (or neighbourhood average), also known as a boxcar filter.

For each pixel i,j, you need to take the sum of (i-1,j-1), (i-1,j), (i-1,j+1), (i,j-1), (i,j),(i,j+1),(i+1,j-1),(i+1,j),(i+1,j+1), then divide by 9 (for a 3x3 average). For this to work, you need to not consider the pixels on the image edge, which do not have 9 neighbours (so you start at pixel (1,1), for example). The output image will be a pixel smaller on each side. Alternatively, you can mirror values out to add an extra line to your input image which will make the output image the same size as the original.

There are more efficient ways of doing this, for example using FFT based convolution; these methods are faster because they don't require looping.

Comment: hello there, the idea you proposed gave me some kind of patterned picture, the blurring didn't work

Comment: @bnjamin , in the edges you will bad by zero , could you give sample code

Comment: As I mention, you need to either pad the image with a constant, mirror or extend edges. Otherwise, the "zeros" in the kernel will affect the average for windows on the edges.